# Diferencia entre classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase

Tengo una duda al crear una clase:

```
class:

class():

class(object):
```

¿Cuál sería la diferencia entre estas tres?

Comment: Ninguna de las tres líneas compila.

Comment: no entiendo, por ejemplo la class(object), espera un objecto  de otra classe la class: seria una classe normal? y class() ?

Comment: class(): es lo mismo que class: pero con paréntesis, de hecho si vas a dejar parentecis vacios es mejor no poner nada, y como dices class(object): es una clase que espera objetos de otro, mas conocido como herencia en clases si no me equivoco, [documentacion](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: okei okei, ahora lo entiendo,  Gracias!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes poner un nombre a tu clase, si no, no funcionará, por ejemplo el nombre `prueba`:

```
class Prueba:
    pass
```

Ahora vamos a ver que **las tres formas son exactamente lo mismo**:

1. `class Prueba:` Es la forma más convencional de hacerlo en Python, ya que es la que te hace **escribir lo menos posible**
2. `class Prueba()`: Exactamente igual que la anterior, tienes que escribir los parentesis, y desde mi punto de vista lo hace más feo visualmente (esto es una opinión personal porque estoy acostumbrado al primer método).
3. `class Prueba(object)`: Ninguna diferencia con los anteriores, ya que **por defecto** todas las clases en Python heredan de `object` por lo que **no es necesario indicarlo**

Ahora tu pregunta supongo que será, **¿Entonces por qué existen estas tres formas, si son iguales?**

- En Python 2 (ya no recibe soporte y no está recomendado usarlo) funcionaban de forma distinta. Y se han quedado distintas formas por compatibilidades de código.
- Actualmente en Python, **no solo las clases, todos los tipos heredan de la clase `object`**, pero antiguamente no era así, por ejemplo `int`, `list` ... tenían sus propios tipos y no heredaban de `object`. Esto se unífico para simplificar el lenguaje.

Demostramos todo lo afirmado:

```
class Prueba:
    pass

print(issubclass(Prueba, object))
print(issubclass(int, object))
print(issubclass(float, object))
print(issubclass(tuple, object))
```

**Salida:**

```
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: Un comentario de estilo: los nombres de clase deberían estar _capitalizados_: `class Prueba(object):...`

Comment: Tienes razón Chema, gracias por apuntarlo me había despistado. Lo he editado! Gracias.

Comment: No es obligatorio a nivel sintaxis que los nombres de clase estén capitalizados, sin embargo, se hace por convenio y prolijidad. Solo pongo este comentario para aclarar esto.